# Как ограничить длину выводимой строки через std::cout?

Tags: c++, строки, c++98

Как ограничить длину выводимой строки через `std::cout`, используя библиотеку **<iomanip>** ?
Например, у меня строка `"Hello World!"`, и я хочу ограничить вывод до 10 символов, чтобы на выходе получить `"Hello Worl"`. Есть метод `std::setw(10)`, но несмотря на то, что он устанавливает ширину, он позволяет выводить строки длиной более, чем 10

Comment: цикл пропиши по чарам и все

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если кратко, то нормального способа нет. Особенно в рамках c++98. Грустно, но факт.

Самое простое, что можно сделать — это использовать старый-добрый Си'шный `printf`:

```
printf("%.10s", "Hello World!");
```

Можно также вручную вывести по символу — это оптимальный вариант:

```
const char *s = "Hello world!";
for(size_t i=0; i<10 && *s; i++, s++) {
  std::cout.put(*s)
}
```

---

#### Другие способы

Можно грязно и сердито обрезать строку с помощью `std::string` (субоптимально, зато в одну строку):

```
std::cout << std::string("Hello World!").substr(0,10);
```

Немного более эффективно это можно сделать как-то так

```
std::string str("Hello World!");
if(str.size()>10) {str.resize(10)};
std::cout << str;
```

Если `"Hello World!"` — это изначально `std::string`, то можно вывести по символу в stl-стиле:

```
std::string str("Hello World!");
std::string:const_iterator last = str.size>10 ? std::advance(str.cbegin(),10) : str.сend() ;
std::copy(str.cbegin(), last, std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout));
```

---

#### C++17

Начиная с с++17 появился `std::string_view` с его помощью это также можно сделать почти оптимально:

```
std::cout << std::string_view("Hello World!").substr(0,10);
```

В отличии от варианта с `std::string` это не приводит к копированию данных, но всё же в сравнении с посимвольной записью несколько субоптимально т.к. сначала определяет длину строки.

---

#### C++20

В С++20 в стандарт наконец-то добавили нормальный форматированный вывод (AFAIK на данный момент (август 2021), это реализовано только msvc):

```
std::cout << std::format("{:.10}", "Hello World!");
```

или

```
std::format_to(std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout),"{:.10}", "Hello World!");
```